# Angular 2 | How to set uppercase all value when ngSubmit is trigger

Tags: angular

How can i set to all uppercase input value when ngSubmit is triggered. We can do pipe here but i want to know if their is any other way that can we set to uppercase all input value when submitting.

Comment: are you using reactive forms?

Comment: yes im using reactive form for angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ReactiveForms, then it should be quite trivial just to transform your text before submitting.

#### Step1: Injecting `UpperCasePipe`:

```
constructor(private uppercasePipe: UpperCasePipe) {

}
```

#### Step2: Transform your values using the pipe:

```
onSubmit() {
    //get the current input value of the form
    const username = this.myForm.controls.username.value;

    //tranform the field to uppercase
    const usernameUpperCase = this.uppercasePipe.transform(username);

    //patch the field
    myForm.controls.username.patchValue(usernameUpperCase);

}
```

Note: `patchValue` will update the form values, aka user can literally see in the form (html) being updated to all uppercase. If you just want to silently transform the value and post to server, don't use `patchValue`:

```
onSubmit() {
    let formData = this.myForm.value;
    formData.username = this.uppercasePipe.transform(formData.username);
    //post to server without updating the form value
    myService.postToServer(formData);
}
```

#### Reminder:

Remember to import your necessary modules. `UpperCasePipe` is in `@angular/common`

#### Edit:

If you are using `[(ngModel)]`, simply transform only that property in your component:

HTML:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
    <input name="first" ngModel  #first="ngModel">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<p>First name value: {{ first.value }}</p>
```

Component:

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    console.log(f.value);  // { first: '' }
    const firstNameUppercase = this.uppercasePipe.transform(f.value.firstName)
}
```

Read the docs. They are helpful and contains everything you need.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

https://angular.io/api/common/UpperCasePipe

Comment: thanks for this. so we need to call that uppercasepipe service in order to transfer all input value to uppercase when submitting the form to server.

Comment: can you show to me also on how to set uppercase value when submitting form that not using reactive forms?

Comment: @JydonMah by not using reactive forms do you mean you are using `ngModel` throughout? Anyway the gist is still the same. As long as you can get hold of your input values, you can always transform it using the pipe; before submitting.

Comment: yes using ngModel. so it is same approach with your example above? im trying your solution and still i can;t figure it out.

Comment: and what part of angular core should i call when injecting the UpperCasePipe service

Comment: Thanks @CozyAzure finally got it.

Comment: how about the the boolean value? transform method only accepts string value.

Comment: @JydonMah of course. Why do you need to transform a boolean value? `true` is different from `'true'` and is different from `'TRUE'`. Are you trying to stringify the whole object?

Comment: yes that's what i want to do. anyways i can do it in displaying using pipe {{  myValue.value | uppercase }} but i want to make all uppercase even boolean value in submitting forms :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148843/discussion-between-cozyazure-and-jydon-mah).